# Why does the position scroll up when I change the routes?

Tags: angular

I added router animations to the project. When I click on the button that moves to another router the animation starts to run but you can see how for a moment the scroll goes to the top of the page. Scroll does not stay in the same position as the button was clicked. People show how nice the router animation is but they show it when there is no scroll.

I remind you that if we switch from a router with a scroll on a router without a scroll then miracles happen with the scroll

[image]
[image]

Thank you for your help :)

Edit:

I added a new photo showing the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now am not getting much of your scenario, but as far I get through, I suggest you put some min-height to your container so that when router changes your view, the container should be visible.